# Errno 13 Permission Denied in a directory I just created

Tags: python, permissions

I can create a folder on my Windows desktop:

```
download_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop'), (file_downloads')
try:
    os.mkdir(download_path)
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

But when I try to download a file to it:

```
def download(file_names):
    for file in file_names:
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(file, download_path, file.split('/')[-1])
            print(f'Successfully downloaded {file}')
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```

I get this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have tried other directories where I have changed the permissions so that `Everyone` has Full Control and I still get the same error. I have also tried running the Python file from the command line as an administrator and I still get the same error.

Comment: I sometimes get this kind of problem on Windows because an antivirus program has locked the directory to scan for viruses.  You could try pausing the antivirus program and see if the problem goes away.  Then look for solutions which avoid that, (looping and sleeping until directory is not locked).

Comment: Your paramters in `urlretrieve(...` are faulty. Read [urllib.request.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)